# Is it possible to specify unique combinations of continuous predictor variables using emmeans() with a single call?

Tags: r, prediction, lm, emmeans

I am using emmeans() in R to estimate marginal means after fitting a linear model with a single knot. I know we can be explicit about at what values the predictor should be set to using `at = list(x = c())`. I need to create my model by defining a new variable for the knot, which makes creating this `at =` more complicated.

Reproducible Example:

```
#
library(dplyr)
library(emmeans)
set.seed(080723)

# Simulate data
n <- 1000
df <- data.frame(x = runif(n, 0, 30))
df <- df%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(y = case_when(
  x <= 15 ~ (2*x) + rnorm(1, 0, 5),
  x > 15 ~ (2*x) + (5*(x-15)) + rnorm(1, 0, 5)
  ))%>%
  ungroup()

# Plot the simulated data
plot(df$x, df$y, pch = 16, col = "blue", xlab = "x", ylab = "y")

# Manually add a covariate to act as a spline in regression
df <- df%>%mutate(xk_15 = case_when(
  x <= 15 ~ 0,
  x > 15 ~ x-15
))

# LM using that covariate
m1 <- lm(y ~ x + xk_15, data = df)
summary(m1)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.53337    0.39976  -1.334    0.182    
x            2.01647    0.03994  50.493   <2e-16 ***
xk_15        4.99538    0.07298  68.452   <2e-16 ***
```

Now, suppose I would like the estimated marginal mean for y when x = 5, 10, 15, and 20. However, given my model formulation I also need to specify xk_15. To match the desired values of x, the values for xk_15 should be 0, 0, 0, 5, respectively.

I can accomplish this by running emmeans() twice.

First,

```
emmeans(m1, "x", at = list(x=c(5,10,15), xk_15=c(0)))

x emmean    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
  5   9.55 0.248 997     9.06     10.0
 10  19.63 0.206 997    19.23     20.0
 15  29.71 0.322 997    29.08     30.3
```

and then,

```
emmeans(m1, "x", at = list(x=c(20), xk_15=c(5)))

 x emmean    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 20   64.8 0.203 997     64.4     65.2
```

My question is: **Is there a way to accomplish this in a single call?**
Conceptually, something like `emmeans(m1, "x" , at = list(x=c(5,10,15,20),xk_15=c(0,0,0,5)))`, where it would match the elements of each `at =`  vector. Note, that code does not work.

I present the current spline setup as it is the driving force for me, but I can imagine this could be generalized for any two continuous predictor variables using emmeans(). Of course I can get the desired estimated marginal means calling emmeans() twice as shown, but it would be nice to be able to specify specific combinations of continuous predictors in a single line, especially if there were many combinations of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `emmeans` a single time using both variables and filter out the rows you don't want:

```r
emmeans(m1, specs = c("x", "xk_15"), 
        at = list(x = c(5, 10, 15, 20), xk_15 = c(0, 5)))
  as_tibble() %>%
  filter((x < 20 & xk_15 == 0) | (x == 20 & xk_15 == 5))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 7
#>       x xk_15 emmean    SE    df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     5     0   10.0 0.256   997     9.51     10.5
#> 2    10     0   19.9 0.207   997    19.5      20.3
#> 3    15     0   29.7 0.324   997    29.1      30.3
#> 4    20     5   64.8 0.209   997    64.4      65.2
```

Though if this is something you want to do frequently with an `lm`, it's straightforward to get the same result without `emmeans`, for example the following function:

```r
emmeans2 <- function(obj, data) {
  data %>%
    cbind(predict(object = obj, newdata = ., se.fit = TRUE)[1:3]) %>%
    mutate(lower.CL = fit - 1.96 * se.fit, upper.CL = fit + 1.96 * se.fit) %>%
    rename(emmean = fit, SE = se.fit)
}
  
emmeans2(m1, data.frame(x=c(5, 10, 15, 20), xk_15=c(0, 0, 0, 5)))
#>    x xk_15   emmean        SE  df  lower.CL upper.CL
#> 1  5     0 10.01255 0.2557274 997  9.511327 10.51378
#> 2 10     0 19.86030 0.2067146 997 19.455142 20.26546
#> 3 15     0 29.70805 0.3240371 997 29.072940 30.34317
#> 4 20     5 64.78476 0.2085883 997 64.375931 65.19360
```

Of course, this only does a tiny fraction of what `emmeans` can do, but it works perfectly well in simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
grid_data <- data.frame(x=c(5, 10, 15, 20), xk_15=c(0, 0, 0, 5))

emm <- emmeans(m1, specs = "x", grid = grid_data)
print(emm)
```

This way, you will able to accomplish  in a single call.

Comment: Using your code, I get the following error when running the emmeans() line: Error in .my.vcov(object, ...) : 
  vcov. must be a function or a square matrix